# How to loop through worksheets, copying and pasting parts of columns to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that will copy specific cells from a range of worksheets, namely the range H6:H, and then will copy those cells into columns on another singular worksheet, pasting first into column A, then column B, then C, and so forth, including the name of the worksheet they were taken from in the top row. I'm sure this is very simple to do, but I am new to VBA and I am not sure of the correct way to do this.

I've written some code which is kind of a rough outline of how I think it should be, but I'm not really sure about how well suited to my purpose it is.

```
Dim names As Variant
Dim name As Variant
Dim i as Integer
names = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")
For Each name In names
    i = i + 1
    With Sheets(name)
        Sheets(name).Select
        Range(“H6:H”).copy
        Sheets("Task_Completion_Data").Select
        Range("A1+i").Select 'No way this is correct syntax, just a placeholder
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
Next name
```

I haven't included anything for pasting the name of the sheet the data is copied from to the top row, as I have no idea how I would do that. I do receive an error message which states: "Compile Error. Expected list separator or )" on row 9 (Range(“H6:H”).copy). If anyone could be of assistance I would greatly appreciate it!

Here are pictures of what the given answer's code generates, what the source material column looks like, and the actual data type inside of each column.[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a bit of a stab in the dark, but give this a try.

I've assumed you want to copy H6 down the last used cell in H.

The results will be copied B2, C2 etc (use `Offset` to move along the row) and the sheet names will go in B1, C1 etc.

EDIT: `i` amended so that you start output in A (as per your question).

```
Sub x()

Dim names As Variant
Dim name As Variant
Dim i As Long

names = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")

For Each name In names
    'i = i + 1
    With Sheets(name)
        .Range("H6", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy _
                    Sheets("Task_Completion_Data").Range("A2").Offset(, i)
    End With
    Sheets("Task_Completion_Data").Range("A1").Offset(, i).Value = name
    i = i + 1
Next name

End Sub
```

Comment: What, you're not going to add the sheet name as a column header?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help SJR. this code did copy the names of the sheets into the desired cells, but it did not do the same for the accompanying data from each column

Comment: Does it do anything? Perhaps you are copying formulae?

Comment: @SJR It's supposed to be copying timestamps. And it does copy all of the names of the worksheets the data was taken from, but it doesn't copy the actual data itself (the timestamps).

Comment: Can't see anything obvious. Post a screenshot perhaps? Step through the code to see what's going on.

Comment: Oh, okay, maybe there's just something really wrong with how I put it in or something? Either way I added pictures of what my end result is, some of the cells being copied, and the data that is inside each of the cells.

Comment: Managed to sort it out?

Comment: No, but you did your best to answer the question so I figured I would give you credit for it lol not your fault im very shaky with VBA at best

Comment: It  finally did work exactly as it was supposed to. Thank you so much SJR!